# Magento controllers Override Not working

Tags: magento-enterprise, overrides, controllers

I am trying to override a file in controllers directory of the Amazon Payments module. I have followed several tutorials with no luck at overriding the controllers. I need to override _getOnepage() in Checkout.php.

### Community Plugin Code

**app/code/community/Amazon/Payments/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category    Amazon
 * @package     Amazon_Payments
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Amazon.com
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amazon_Payments>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </Amazon_Payments>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <amazon_payments>
                <class>Amazon_Payments_Block</class>
            </amazon_payments>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <amazon_payments>
                <class>Amazon_Payments_Model</class>
            </amazon_payments>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_creditmemo>Amazon_Payments_Model_Order_Creditmemo</order_creditmemo>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <amazon_payments>
                <class>Amazon_Payments_Helper</class>
            </amazon_payments>
        </helpers>
        <template>
            <email>
               <amazon_payments_async_decline>
                   <label>Amazon Payments Async Decline</label>
                   <file>amazon_payments_async_decline.html</file>
                   <type>html</type>
               </amazon_payments_async_decline>
            </email>
        </template>
        <rewrite>
            <amazon_payments_checkout>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/amazon_payments#]]></from>
                <to>/amazon_payments/checkout</to>
            </amazon_payments_checkout>
        </rewrite>
        <resources>
            <payments_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amazon_Payments</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </payments_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Amazon_Payments after="Mage_Adminhtml">Amazon_Payments_Adminhtml</Amazon_Payments>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <tax>
                    <file>amazon_payments.xml</file>
                </tax>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <amazon_payments>
                        <class>Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer_Adminhtml</class>
                        <method>addAsyncButton</method>
                    </amazon_payments>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <amazon_payments_observer>
                        <class>Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer_Order</class>
                        <method>closeAmazonOrder</method>
                    </amazon_payments_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <cart_updatepost>/checkout/cart/updatePost</cart_updatepost>
            <checkout_amazon>/checkout/amazon_payments</checkout_amazon>
            <amazon_checkout>/amazon_payments/checkout</amazon_checkout>
        </secure_url>
        <routers>
            <amazon_payments>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amazon_Payments</module>
                    <frontName>amazon_payments</frontName>
                </args>
            </amazon_payments>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <amazon_payments>
                    <file>amazon_payments.xml</file>
                </amazon_payments>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                   <amazon_payments_observer>
                      <class>Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer_Onepage</class>
                      <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                   </amazon_payments_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <amazon_payments_observer>
                        <class>Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer_Order</class>
                        <method>updateCustomerAddress</method>
                    </amazon_payments_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
                <observers>
                    <amazon_payments_observer>
                        <class>Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer_Action</class>
                        <method>secureCart</method>
                    </amazon_payments_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
            <custom_quote_process>
                <observers>
                    <amazon_payments_observer>
                        <class>Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer_Onepage</class>
                        <method>clearShippingAddress</method>
                    </amazon_payments_observer>
                </observers>
            </custom_quote_process>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <amazon_payments>
                <title>Amazon Payments</title>
                <model>amazon_payments/paymentMethod</model>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
                <show_pay_cart>1</show_pay_cart>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <active>1</active>
                <secure_cart>1</secure_cart>
                <button_type>PwA</button_type>
                <button_color>Gold</button_color>
                <button_size>medium</button_size>
                <button_badge>1</button_badge>
            </amazon_payments>
        </payment>
    </default>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <amazon_payments_async>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>amazon_payments/async::cron</model></run>
            </amazon_payments_async>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**app/code/community/Amazon/Payments/controllers/OnepageController.php**

```
class Amazon_Payments_OnepageController extends Amazon_Payments_Controller_Checkout
{
    ...

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // placeholder required
    }

    ...
}
```

---

### My Override Code

**app/code/local/KNG/Amazon/Payments/controllers/OnepageController.php**

```
require_once 'Amazon/Payments/controllers/OnepageController.php';
class KNG_Amazon_Payments_OnepageController extends Amazon_Payments_OnepageController 
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_getOnepage()->savePayment(array(
                'method' => 'amazon_payments',
                'additional_information' => array(
                        'order_reference' => $this->getAmazonOrderReferenceId(),
                )
        ));
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/KNG/Amazon/Payments/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <KNG_Amazon_Payments>
            <version>1.3.0.1</version>
        </KNG_Amazon_Payments>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <amazon_payments>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <KNG_Amazon_Payments before="Amazon_Payments">KNG_Amazon_Payments</KNG_Amazon_Payments>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </amazon_payments>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/KNG_Amazon/Payments.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <KNG_Amazon_Payments>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Amazon_Payments />
            </depends>
        </KNG_Amazon_Payments>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controllers folders have to be 3 folders deep from code pool.

The controllers folder I am trying to get working is 4 folders deep in the code pool.

**app/code/local/KNG/Amazon/Payments/controllers/OnepageController.php**

1. KNG
2. Amazon
3. Payments
4. controllers

When I changed all the files to be under Amazonpayments and changed the path of my controller to path below, then everything worked, because now the controllers folder is only 3 folders deep from the code pool.

**app/code/local/KNG/Amazonpayments/controllers/OnepageController.php**

1. KNG
2. Amazonpayments
3. controllers